# installed program "cppcheck" but command "where cppcheck" (on windows command line) can't find anything

Tags: windows, windows-console, cppcheck

I downloaded and installed the program "cppcheck" (http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/).

This program has both a GUI (which I can access without problems) and a command line interface.
However, when I go to the windows command prompt and type "where cppcheck", nothing can be found.

Am I crazy? Or is the command line interface for cppcheck only accessible on Unix systems?

Comment: This is off topic for stack overflow.  You probably want SuperUser.  The where command checks the local directory and the PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I usually don't work with Windows, I didn't realise that the "where" command just looks in the current folder and child folders of the current folder. That's why I didn't get any results.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add it in the environment variables since the cppcheck installer does not add it automatically. This way you can use the where command from any folder as it also checks the environment variables too.